# Merging to arrays together

Tags: php, arrays, merge, image-uploading

I am trying to merge to arrays. At least what as far as i know are two arrays. However the PHP returns an error saying the first is not an array.

My end goal is to upload the image, then get the existing data in my textfile, append the new results to the end of the existing data and then write it all back to the database. This way it doesn't over write the file each time a new image is uploaded and therefore you can keep uploading more and more images.

Here is my php:

```
<?php
$sFileName = "imgDB.txt";
$temp = "temp.txt";

for($i=0 ; $i < count($_FILES) ; $i++){
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file-'.$i]['tmp_name'] , "img/". $_FILES['file-
'.$i]['name'] );
}


// Get the content of the file!
$sImgs = file_get_contents($sFileName); //gets a string from the file.
$ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs); //converts the string to an array.


$aOutPut = array_merge ($ajImgs, $_FILES);

$aSendToFile = json_encode($aOutPut, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | 
JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents($sFileName, $aSendToFile);
```

Comment: Pass `true` as a second argument to `json_decode()` to get an array. Else you get an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
$ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs);
```

By default, `json_decode()` returns an object.  If you want an array you can pass boolean `true` as the optional second argument:

```
$ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs,1);
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

However, if the file "imgDB.txt" is empty you might also get boolean `false` returned from `json_decode()`, so you can check the make sure you've got an array like this:

```
$ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs,1) ?: array();
```

This is shorthand for:

```
if (json_decode($sImgs,1) != false) {
    $ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs,1);
} else {
    $ajImgs = array();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To resolve the images in the json getting overwritten, *while still avoiding dupes* I suggest building a new array, using the filename as the key:

```
// initialize a new array for use below
$files = array();
for($i=0 ; $i < count($_FILES) ; $i++){
    /* for some reason your application posts some empty files
       without going to deep into the javascript side,
       here is a simple way to ignore those */
    if (empty($_FILES['file-'.$i]['size'])) continue; 
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file-'.$i]['tmp_name'] , "img/". $_FILES['file-'.$i]['name'] );

    // now we build a new array using filenames as array keys
    $files[$_FILES['file-'.$i]['name']] = $_FILES['file-'.$i];

    // if you don't care about dupes you can use a numeric key like this
    // $files[] = $_FILES['file-'.$i];
}

// now do your merge with this new array
$aOutPut = array_merge ($ajImgs, $files);
```

The above has been tested and is working for me.  There's probably a better way to handle this, like *adding the files directly to the decoded json*, but rewriting the entire app is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks @billynoah that solved my error :). However its still not quite working. Do you or anyone else know why my arrays are not merging. My code instead overwrites the array each time it runs instead of putting them together.

Comment: @Wonx2150 - If the keys are strings and are the same, array merge will overwrite the former with the later.  It looks like you are using something like `file-1`, `file-2`, etc.  If you can change them to simply use numeric keys, `array_merge()` will take care of reindexing them.  If not, you'll need to do something to rename them so they are unique.  Without knowing how `$_FILES` is generated it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I could use some help if you don't mind. I have tried to change them to numeric keys, though i maybe on the wrong track. I've tried to get them to be higher than the value of the array or giving them random numbers as the file name. None of it does the trick.

Here is the URL to the files as it maybe easier if you look at the files instead of code segments.[link](http://wonx.dk/imgUploader/ImgUploader.zip)

Comment: there are all kinds of problems with the php. without going to deep into it, I've made some changes to get things working as *I believe* they are supposed to.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the second parameter for json_decode().

```
$ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs, true);
```